# In Python, retrieving Xml attribute value

Tags: python, xml

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString, parse

dom = parse('response.xml')

xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].toxml()
```

How do I get the attribute 'href' of the xml for rel="alternate":

```
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfyKPbic&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
  <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gf7zhyKPbic/responses'/>
```

Comment: Among other errors, this line `dom = parseString(data) dom = parse('response.xml')` is invalid python syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DOC = """<root>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfyKPbic&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
  <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gf7zhyKPbic/responses'/>
</root>"""
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString, parse
dom = parseString(DOC)
hreflist= [elt.getAttribute("href") for elt in dom.getElementsByTagName('link')  if elt.getAttribute("rel")=="alternate"]
for href in hreflist:
    print(href)
```